# Problems with installing bib.dll

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I tried installing adobe illustrator, and it kept bringing out an error message that I don't have bib.dll installed on my system. I downloaded bib.dll from the net, but, how do i install it on my system? I tried installing it, but it keeps telling me that no app can open this file, download from the web. I did that, downloaded open freely software, but it still didn't work after opening. what do i do?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a pirated version of Illustrator?

Answer (score -1):

1. Copy the .dll file to the folder `C:\Windows\System32\`
2. Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the `Run` dialog (you might also see this in your start menu)
3. Type `regsvr32 bib.dll` and click `OK`